# why overload operator&& error?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++11

I try write a Expression templates.

```
   template<typename Tag>
struct Expr{
    tuple<Tag> value;
};
struct logic_and{};

template<typename T>
struct isExpr{enum{value=0};};
template<typename Tag>
struct isExpr<Expr<Tag>>{enum{value=1};};

template<typename L,typename R,typename=std::enable_if<isExpr<L>::value||isExpr<R>::value> >
Expr<logic_and> operator&&(const L&,const R&)
{
   return {};
}
```

but mingw gcc 4.8.1 error:

```
...include\c++\ext\string_conversions.h||In instantiation of '_Ret __gnu_cxx::__stoa(_TRet (*)(const _CharT*, _CharT**, _Base ...), const char*, const _CharT*, std::size_t*, _Base ...) [with _TRet = long int; _Ret = int; _CharT = char; _Base = {int}; std::size_t = long long unsigned int]':|
...include\c++\bits\basic_string.h|2825|required from here|
...include\c++\ext\string_conversions.h|67|error: no match for 'operator||' (operand types are 'bool' and 'Expr<logic_and>')|
...include\c++\ext\string_conversions.h|67|note: candidate is:|
...include\c++\ext\string_conversions.h|67|note: operator||(bool, bool) <built-in>|
...include\c++\ext\string_conversions.h|67|note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'Expr<logic_and>' to 'bool'|
...include\c++\ext\string_conversions.h||In instantiation of '_Ret __gnu_cxx::__stoa(_TRet (*)(const _CharT*, _CharT**, _Base ...), const char*, const _CharT*, std::size_t*, _Base ...) [with _TRet = long int; _Ret = long int; _CharT = char; _Base = {int}; std::size_t = long long unsigned int]':|
```

looks find a bool result...If I replace to

```
template<typename L,typename R,typename=std::enable_if<isExpr<L>::value||isExpr<R>::value> >
Expr<logic_and> operator||(const L&,const R&)
{
   return {};
}
```

or  replace to

```
template<typename L,typename R,typename=std::enable_if<isExpr<L>::value||isExpr<R>::value> >
bool operator&&(const L&,const R&)
{
   return {};
}
```

all pass! is gcc bug? how can I fix it?

**edit:** sorry my Misleading to enable_if....now I  reproduce the bug:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>
namespace TestFoo{
struct Tag {};
struct shift_left:Tag {};
struct shift_right:Tag {};
struct multiplies:Tag {};
struct divides:Tag {};
struct modulus:Tag {};
struct plus:Tag {};
struct minus:Tag {};
struct less:Tag {};
struct greater:Tag {};
struct less_equal:Tag {};
struct greater_equal:Tag {};
struct equal_to:Tag {};
struct not_equal_to:Tag {};
struct logical_or:Tag {};
struct logical_and:Tag {};
struct bitwise_and:Tag {};
struct bitwise_or:Tag {};
struct bitwise_xor:Tag {};
struct shift_left_assign:Tag {};
struct shift_right_assign:Tag {};
struct multiplies_assign:Tag {};
struct divides_assign:Tag {};
struct modulus_assign:Tag {};
struct plus_assign:Tag {};
struct minus_assign:Tag {};
struct bitwise_and_assign:Tag {};
struct bitwise_or_assign:Tag {};
struct bitwise_xor_assign:Tag {};


template<typename Tag,typename...ARGS>
class Expr
{

public:
    template<typename...SRC>
    Expr(SRC const&...src){

    }
private:
};
template<typename T>
struct is_expr{
    enum{value=0};
};
template<typename Tag,typename...ARGS>
struct is_expr<Expr<Tag,ARGS...>>{
    enum{value=sizeof...(ARGS)};
};

#define BinaryOp(op,name)   \
template<typename L,typename R,typename=typename std::enable_if<is_expr<L>::value||is_expr<R>::value>::type>\
Expr<name,L,R> operator op(const L&l,const R&r)\
{\
   return  {std::forward<const L&>(l),std::forward<const R&>(r)};\
}

BinaryOp(<<,shift_left)
BinaryOp(>>,shift_right)
BinaryOp(*,multiplies)
BinaryOp(%,modulus)
BinaryOp(+,plus)
BinaryOp(-,minus)
BinaryOp(<,less)
BinaryOp(>,greater)
BinaryOp(<=,less_equal)
BinaryOp(>=,greater_equal)
BinaryOp(==,equal_to)
BinaryOp(!=,not_equal_to)
BinaryOp(||,logical_or)
BinaryOp(&&,logical_and)

}
```

.cpp :

```
#include "test.h"

using namespace TestFoo;//using namespace Appear bug
void test(){  
}
```

if I delete   `BinaryOp(&&,logical_and)` ,or not using namespace in .cpp,or delete all std::forward ,Compile successfully. Otherwise eat memory Until failure.

Comment: I think you wanted to used `std::enable_if_t`... (or add missing `typename` and `::type`)

Comment: @jarod42 you are right.this sample is miss typename and ::type....but return bool or operator|| is pass! and in my really work(define all operator overload and Expr more Complex),if not Commented operator&& overload Compiler stop work on memory alloc error...

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, also clang is not working

Comment: One of your 'replace to's look identical to the original?

Comment: In addition `Expr<logic_and>` is not convertible to `bool`

Comment: @Jarod42 now I Finally cut out errors As little code....

Comment: @fe263 I do not believe that is a http://sscce.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
template<typename L, typename R, typename = typename std::enable_if<is_expr<L>::value &&    is_expr<R>::value>::type>
Expr<name, L, R> operator op(const L&l, const R&r);
```

You go in (compiler) recursive `operator ||`: this operator may evaluate the (unnamed) **enum** `is_expr<L>::value` with the **enum** `is_expr<R>::value` which need to take into account `is_expr<decltype(is_expr<L>::value)>::value`...

A solution is to replace the `enum` by a `static constexpr std::size_t`. (see https://ideone.com/pqhmv1)

Comment: yes!you are right.but I do not understand why is_expr<R> look into is_expr<L>::value...

Comment: Compiler has to compute `enum || enum`, so your provided `operator ||` may be a candidate, but it has to compute first `is_expr<L>::value || is_expr<R>::value` with is also an other `enum || enum`... And so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::enable_if<isExpr<L>::value||isExpr<R>::value>
```

the above is a valid type regardless of what is inside the `<>` of `enable_if`.

```
typename std::enable_if<isExpr<L>::value||isExpr<R>::value>::type
```

is a valid type if and only if the `bool` expression in the `<>` of `enable_if` is `true`.

In short, you are not doing SFINAE successfully, so things behaving strangely is expected.  In particular, your overloaded operator claims to handle `const bool&||const bool&` and many other pairs of types it has no business messing around with.

I cannot decode the error, but first fix the code.